# Learning the distribution of a continuous variable using LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, reinforcement-learning, pytorch

I am trying to implement the following paper : https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.10701.pdf. In order, to estimate the priors of the hidden states which have continuous values, the authors use a LSTM. I have never done this before, and I was wondering If:

- It is possible to directly do this, or should I make an assumption about the distribution and use the reparameterization trick, or is estimating `p(z_{i}|z_{i-1})` equivalent to estimating `z_{i}` ?
- In the `HalfCheetah` environment, the `z_{i}` is a function of the episod. When trying to estimate `p(z_{i}|z_{i-1})` doesn't the way of feeding data affect the learned distribution ?